Showing that certain polynomials defined recursively have simple roots.
Let $f_0(z)=z$, and define recursively $f_{i}(z)=zf_{i-1}(z)-f_{i-1}(z)+1$, for all $i \geq 1$. I would like to show that $f_i(z)$ has at least a simple root (this should be true), for any $i$. I can see this if the degree of $f_i$ is odd, and in that case the simple root would be $z=0$.
Maybe this is a silly question, but I'd need it to find a reduced point in a certain scheme. For this reason, I will also insert "Algebraic Geometry" in the tags.

A non-recursive definition is
$$ f_i(z) = \frac{(z-1)^{i+2}-1}{z-2} $$
So the roots of $f_i(z)$ are $r+1$ where $r$ is a $(i+2)$'th root of unity other than $1$.  These are all simple roots.

Great! Thank you!
